# Implementation of DPLL algorithm in Prolog

Tags: algorithm, implementation, prolog

I'm trying to apply the simplified algorithm in Prolog, but I'm not a Prolog master. I need it without any mistakes, so I thought you guys might be able to help.

What is the implementation of DPLL algorithm in Prolog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting "dpll algorithm prolog code" into Google returns this very nice source file as the first result. It's probably way too neat and nice to be handed in as homework without extensive cutting-down and messing-up.

http://www.mscs.mu.edu/~cstruble/class/cosc159/spring2004/code/dpll.pl

The second result is this question page here, as SO is highly ranked.

Comment: Yeah it's really smooth and neat!! thx rly .. and this is not the main homework .. it's just like 5% of it .. i just didn't want to spend more time while i don't  have enough of it already .. thank you again .. that was a lot of help!!

Comment: Unfortunately the link is broken now. But there is some stuff here: http://code.google.com/p/mlcs/downloads/detail?name=mlcs-programs-3-3-1.zip